# Check Network connections in android

Tags: android

how to check whether network is connected or not in android mobile phone..(network means not internet connection,, its simple mobile network like IDEA,AIRTEL etc..) please help me

Comment: refer this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6357603/problem-in-detecting-internet-connection-in-android/6357668#6357668

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok so you just want to check the network connections?
This method seems to be pretty good for it!
http://smartandroidians.blogspot.co.uk/2010/03/checking-network-connection-in-android.html
Give that a go and hopefully that'll sort it :)

Comment: In the link what is connection manager.. didnt get that, pls help me out,, thanks for ur help

Comment: It is basically Android's function to check what/who is connected to where :) http://developer.android.com/reference/org/apache/http/conn/ClientConnectionManager.html      Thats the dev link for it :)

Answer (score 0):

You can retrieve both SIM and network  Operator using `TelephonyManager` as:

```
TelephonyManager telephonyManager =((TelephonyManager) 
Context.getSystemService(Context.TELEPHONY_SERVICE));

// Network operator IDEA,AIRTEL...
String networkOperatorName = telephonyManager.getNetworkOperatorName();

// sim operator IDEA,AIRTEL,BSNL,MTNL...
String simOperatorName = telephonyManager.getSimOperatorName();
```

Comment: i don't want operator name.. i just want whether network is there or not.. thank u

Comment: @diordna : i got you i think you will need to find out all available Networks Providers Name ? then plz check-out  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3123697/how-to-get-a-list-of-available-network-providers

Answer (score 0):

Check the [TelephonyManager](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/telephony/TelephonyManager.html) class.
This may help you in many ways.

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
 * Checking whether net connection is available or not.
 * 
 * @param nContext
 * @return true if net connection is avaible otherwise false
 */
public static boolean isNetworkAvailable(Context nContext) {
    boolean isNetAvailable = false;
    if (nContext != null) {
        ConnectivityManager mConnectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) nContext
                .getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        if (mConnectivityManager != null) {
            boolean mobileNetwork = false;
            boolean wifiNetwork = false;
            boolean mobileNetworkConnecetd = false;
            boolean wifiNetworkConnecetd = false;
            NetworkInfo mobileInfo = mConnectivityManager
                    .getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_MOBILE);
            NetworkInfo wifiInfo = mConnectivityManager
                    .getNetworkInfo(ConnectivityManager.TYPE_WIFI);
            if (mobileInfo != null)
                mobileNetwork = mobileInfo.isAvailable();
            if (wifiInfo != null)
                wifiNetwork = wifiInfo.isAvailable();
            if (wifiNetwork == true || mobileNetwork == true) {
                if (mobileInfo != null)
                    mobileNetworkConnecetd = mobileInfo
                            .isConnectedOrConnecting();
                wifiNetworkConnecetd = wifiInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting();
            }
            isNetAvailable = (mobileNetworkConnecetd || wifiNetworkConnecetd);
        }
    }
    return isNetAvailable;

}
```

Also add below tag in manifest permission:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```